# macros and contextual output in C

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to understand following description of macros in a file:

```
/*
 * The following macros provide wrapper calls to the test functions with
 * a default description that indicates the file and line number of the error.
 *
 * The following macros guarantee to evaluate each argument exactly once.
 * This allows constructs such as: if (!TEST_ptr(ptr = MYFOO_malloc(..)))
 * to produce better contextual output than:
 *      ptr = MYFOO_malloc(..);
 *      if (!TEST_ptr(ptr))
 */
```

I could not make sense how the macros are helpful in this scenario as described in the above description?

Comment: Having `TEST_ptr` be a macro instead of a function means that it can provide more useful information about what's happening when if finds a result it doesn't like. It can print the contents of the test it did, and provide more useful information about where that test happened in the source code. The part about evaluating just once is a common issue in macros, but it doesn't seem that that's the subject of your question.

Comment: Please do tell about the 'evaluating just once' issue of macros.

Comment: Show the macro, not just the comment. The author of this text apparently wants to print information about each function call using the special macros `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`. These macros are replaced with the current file name and source line number. This means that inside a called function, they only report the name of the file containing the called function and the line number inside a function. By using a macro in place of a function call, the macro will be replaced where it appears. Its replacement text contains `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`,…

Comment: … and then those will be replaced by the file name and the line number of where the macro appears, rather replaced by the file name and the line number of a called function. However, macro replacement can be finicky, so explaining the details is better with some context. So show the actual macro definitions, not just those comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using macros allows you to make use of [Standard Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html), such as `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`, as indicated by

> a default description that indicates the file and line number of the error.

to silently add debugging information to your function calls.

Here's an example using GCC [Statement Expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) to ensure that expressions used as macro arguments are only evaluated once:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define debug_test_ptr(ptr) ({ \
        void *p = (ptr); \
        fprintf(stderr, "testing %p in %s at line %d.\n", \
                p, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        p; })

#define debug_malloc(sz) ({ \
        size_t s = (sz); \
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc(%zu) called in %s at line %d.\n", \
                s, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        malloc(s); })

int main(void) {
    char *foo;

    if (!debug_test_ptr(foo = debug_malloc(100)))
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");

    free(foo);
}
```

Output:

```
malloc(100) called in info.c at line 19.
testing 0x117a2a0 in info.c at line 19.
```